# Restore i3.desktop and i3-with-shmlog.desktop files after reinstalling i3wm

Tags: 16.04, .desktop, i3-wm

I had installed i3 in my system before, but got rid of it and manually removed `i3.desktop` and `i3-with-shmlog.desktop` in my `/usr/share/xsessions` folder. I reinstalled i3 again, but this time, no `.desktop` files were created. How can I get the i3 to create the `.desktop` file?

Comment: Are you installing *i3* from the official Ubuntu repositories or from any of the Ubuntu repositories mentioned on http://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html? The package *i3-wm* from any of these repositories contains the files in question, so just (re-)installing it should create the files.

Comment: I use the Ubuntu repository. I will give this a try today. Thank you.